# How to mock data with props in your React Functional Component

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-functional-component

In my React application, i am developing a screen using Functional Component. 
I want to populate the data on the screen with mock data until my API is ready. I basically have an Accordion with open state where i want to display the names. Right now, i am hardcoding name to populate that. Later, i will be replacing with the actual data coming from Store. So to do that i am defining the hard coded data like below in my component itself as after the API is ready, my props will have all the required data.

```js
function MyComponent (props) {
    props={
        history: {},
        data:[
          {
            name:’XYZ’,
          },
          {
            name:’ABC’,
          }
        ]
    }

    return (
       <div>Content goes here </div>
     )
}
```

This throws me error. I want to understand if i am doing this correctly as i need to read the data values inside my div.

Answer (score 1):

Props are **immutable**, so you should not change them. 
Instead, you could mock the props that you are *passing* to `MyComponent`

---

Example:
In the parent component:

```
function MyApp() {
  const mockProps={
    history: {},
    data:[
      name:’XYZ’,
    ]
  }

  return <MyComponent {...mockProps}/>
}
```

and in `MyComponent`

```
function MyComponent (props) {
 // do something with props here
 return <div>Content goes here </div>
}
```

Comment: Can you add the sample code for better understanding?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably best to mock this data as coming from parent container, that way when you add Redux library later, you can simply change /where/ props are being sent from.

e.g

in Parent JS:

```
const Parent = props => {
const [accordionData, setData] = useState(['#1', '#2', '#3'])

/ ... rest of component / 

return <Accordion accordionData={accordionData} />

}
```

in

```
const Accordion = props => {

    const { accordionData } = props // pull props from parent component.

    const mapAccordionData = accordionData.map(el => { return <div key={el}>el</div> })

    return mapAccordionData

}
```

Something like this should work.

ParentJS is feeding the accordion an array of  data via parent->child props. Later this will be store->child props. Accordion  (child) is then rendering that data to so the user can see it via divs.

Answer (score 0):

You would **pass** props into a component. They should come from either a parent's component state or a store (like Redux store).

```
function MyComponent(props) {
  return <div>{props.hello}</div>;
}


class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    hello: 'Hello World!',
  }

  render() {
    return <MyComponent hello={this.state.hello} />;
  }
}
```

You can also pass a function that changes the state of the parent making the props also change for `MyComponent`. It won't mutate them but rather return a new state and therefore pass a new set of props.
Let me know if you need any further explanation.

Comment: I am actually trying to figure out a way to use the hardcoded data in MyComponent itself (as later it would be available from store) and i also want to keep my component Functional. Is there any way i can achieve that?

Comment: Then you can store it as a variable external to the function for maximum re-usability.
You can nonetheless pass it into props in any case. Since we're passing static mockData. If you want it to change depending on any action triggered in the UI you would have to use something like what's in my answer or oliver's. Preferably his since he keeps it functional by using React.useState hook.